# E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, sudo

whenever I am sudo I ma getting errors -->
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I don't know what should I do please help me
[image]

Comment: Please do not have pictures of text include the text in the question.

Comment: Please include the contents of the sources list in the body of the question.

Comment: Copy from the terminal and paste into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you accidentally included `sudo` inside the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list`, which shouldn't be there. If you're following [this guide](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-install-etcher-on-ubuntu), the contents of that file should be

```
deb https://deb.etcher.io stable etcher
```

Open a terminal window, type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list`, edit the file so it matches, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> when prompted to save, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save to the same file.

Finally, run `sudo apt update` to refresh your list of packages. Hopefully afterwards you can do `apt` commands again!